# How to <%= link_to %> entire area of <li> in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

In my Navbar, I'm currently linking the phrase "Sign out" to signout_path:

```
    <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete %></li>
```

How can I make the entire area of the li tag become a link so that when I click anywhere in the area of the gradient, it links to home?

CSS for li area when hovered over:

```
     ul.TabNav li:hover {
     background:#666;
     cursor:pointer;
        }
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your CSS:

```
ul.TabNav li a {
  display: block;
}
```

If this doesn't break your layout, it should make the link fill up the available space in the `li` tag, making all of it clickable.

Comment: Perfect. If I wanted to specify the class for positioning could I just add (li, :class => ...., "Sign out") to it?

Comment: Yes you could, like this: `<li class="foo"><%= link_to ...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add padding to the a element, then anything within the padding will be clickable.

```
ul.TabNav li a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Or, as Michael says make it display: block for example

http://jsfiddle.net/MrFdY/3/

Comment: Actually, what you really need to make the `<a>` fill the `<li>` is `display: block;` padding is optional.